# How to avoid license hacking through hosts falsifying on iOS(jailbroken)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, tweak

My app is a not free tweak app for jailbroken iOS device, it uses server side license verification, but someone falsify the hosts from my domain to the fake domain. How can I avoid this hacking?

Comment: Depends how the license verification works.  For example you could exchange certificates.  Sounds like your implementation is lacking somewhat.

Comment: @trojanfoe, yes the verification implementation is simple and has been spied clearly by some hackers. Because I use this simple implementation in the versions at early period, but now, customers use different versions include old and new. To compatible the different versions, I keep using the simple implementation. Most of time it works well, but recently it is hacked by hosts falsifying. Should I use RAS? Or https? I've thought about https, but which looks useless for that hacking way, am I right? Thank you!

Comment: Well it needs to use an encrypted connection, for sure, but the client needs to verify the server, so ensure you have a proper SSL certificate and then you can simply verify the fingerprint.  They are cheap to buy these days.  This question isn't really about programming, though, is it...

Comment: I find it slightly ironic that you're surprised that a verification scheme was broken on a jailbroken device.  That is all.

Comment: @trojanfoe, thank you very much, I got it.